# After installing react native image picker my working code stoped runing

Tags: javascript, react-native, compiler-errors, compilation, imagepicker

After installing react native image picker my working code stoped runing and showing many errors of execution errors and compilation errors of some time
task app:compiledebugkotlin failed
then some times
app:ganeratedebugresvalues failed!! and when solving this then many errors come with different names

i simply run the code and my app was working and runing perfectly this all happen after installing react native image picker thus i dont have any solution i need the image pivker bu5 image picker shows errors like this !!

Comment: Please share the error also.